# Removing quick launch icon from launch pbar at top?

Tags: gnome, launcher, icons

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and had a quick launch link in the top bar, using the older flashback style. See attached screanshot.  There is a link to an old program I have uninstalled and I can't seem to remove it. How can I remove it.  I also have a place on the application launch pull down that has it as well but no longer works.  How do I remove them? [image]

Answer (score 1):

Make right mouse click on the icon with pressed <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> and select *Remove From Panel*:

[image: GNOME FlashBack - remove icon from GNOME Panel]

Notes:
1. If you want to add some item to the GNOME Panel, then use right mouse click with pressed <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> and select *Add to Panel*.
2. If you like this old-fashioned desktop, you may consider to test [MATE DE](http://mate-desktop.org/) (GNOME 2 fork).